# How remove onClick, and then add it again later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a method to enable and disable any element. Disable meaning set the opacity to 0.6 and remove the onClick callbacks. Enable meaning set the opacity to 1 and add the callback again.

My first two attempts failed miserably, the `callback`  methods just got stacked and instead of running it once after each click the method was running more and more times.

```
function disableElement(element){
    var el = $('#'+element); 
    el.css('opacity','0.6');
    el.on('click',null);     //this doesn't work
            el.removeAttr('onClick'); // this doesn't help either.

}

function enableElement(element,callback){
    var el = $('#'+element); 
    el.css('opacity','1');
    el.on('click',callback);            
}
```

Then i tried using the el.data:

```
disableElement:function(element){
        var el = $('#'+element); 
        el.css('opacity','0.6');
        el.data('element-enabled','false');
        //el.click(function (){
        //  alert('disabled');
        //});           
    },
    
    enableElement:function(element,callback){
        console.log('enabling');
        var el = $('#'+element);
        console.log(el);
        if(el.data('element-enabled') == "true")
            return;
        console.log("setOpacity");   
        el.css('opacity','1');
        el.data('element-enabled','true');
        el.click(function(){
            if(el.data('element-enabled') == "true")
                callback();
        }); 
            
    }
```

Now they don't stack, as long as I don't disable it. If I disable and then enable it again, it gets stacked. Which means, if i run enableElement multiple times the callbacks don't stack. But once I run disableElement and then enableElement, if i click in the item, it'll happen twice.

Can achieve that somehow?

**UPDATE**

That was close. The off worked for me but i also had to remove it on the enableElement. Occasionally I have to call it twice, so it was still stacking. Finally this worked, thank you!

```
disableElement:function(element){
    var el = $('#'+element); 
    el.css('opacity','0.6');        
    el.off('click');

},

enableElement:function(element,callback){       
    var el = $('#'+element);
    el.off('click');                    
    el.css('opacity','1');      
    el.on('click',callback);    
        
}
```

Comment: You can use the .off() method to unbind the event handler. http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the event just use `.off()`

```
el.off('click');
```

To add the event back you can just do

```
el.on('click',callback);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.off` as in `.off('click')`.  That will remove all bound events of the `click` type.  [Documentation for `.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Note that if you use `.off` it doesn't return the event or anything, and you can't simply rebind with `.on`.  However, since you have defined the callback in a separate function, you're good to go since you do re-bind as `.on('click', function_name)`.  It's just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Unbind will remove all handlers assigned to the object for some event:

```
$('#foo').unbind('click');
```

You can also set this to some specific function by adding it as a second argument

```
$('#foo').unbind('click', myfunctionname);
```